# iOS game center in dev mode

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, game-center

I'm developing an iOS game and want to add game center functionality.

I don't have finalized screenshots of the game play but after you register them with iTunes connect they can't be changed.

Is there any way to test game center functionality without registering the app? I need IAP, leaderboards and achievements.

am I missing something?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely change the screenshots after you've registered your app with iTunes Connect. I've done this many times before. You'll need to set up the leaderboards and achievements in iTunes Connect in order to test Game Center. It's the only way. These docs might be worth reading up on:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectGameCenter_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013726

Comment: Thanks a lot. Apparently I was mistaken and you can change everything until the app is approved, which doesn't happen when until you request approval, not at the time of registering for iTunes connect.